# Check if an array is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've tried several things which are listed on the forum here, but I can't get this one to work.

So my question: How to check if an array is empty and if so hide an element?

Perhaps I'm doing something completly wrong?

My code:

```
 var listaSelection = {
                "category": [{ value: "1234", text: "Test" }]};

            $("select#list").change(function(){

              $("#cat3").html($("#list option:selected").text());

              var options = '';
              listsa = listaSelection[$(this).val()];

              $('select#listA').empty();

              options += '<option value="">Choose</option>';

              $.each(listsa, function() {
                options += '<option value="' + this.value + '">' + this.text + '</option>';
              });
              if(listsa.length > 0){   
                $('select#listA').append(options);
                $('.zoeken-select.listA').fadeIn(300);
              }else{
                //this array is empty
                return false;
              }

            });
```

The HTML

```
<div class="zoeken-select course">
              <div class="zoeken-value" id="cat2">Selecteer je sector/locatie</div>
              <div class="zoeken-handle"></div>
              <select id="course" class="gui-validate">
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="zoeken-select list">
              <div class="zoeken-value" id="cat3"></div>
              <div class="zoeken-handle"></div>
              <select id="list" class="gui-validate">
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="zoeken-select listA">
              <div class="zoeken-value" id="cat4"></div>
              <div class="zoeken-handle"></div>
              <select id="listA" class="gui-validate">
              </select>
            </div>
```

Comment: I assume `$(this).val()` contains `category` in this example (surrendering `[{value: "1234", text: "Test" }]`)?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [isEmptyObject method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/)

```
jQuery.isEmptyObject({}); // true
jQuery.isEmptyObject({ foo: "bar" }); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

use

`jQuery.isEmptyObject({});`

see [EmptyObject](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/)

Answer (score 0):

for array

```
 var arrayname= [1,2,3,4,5];
```

**now come in else  case**

```
if (arrayname.length === 0) {
  // do your stuff 
}else{
// doyour stuff
 }
```

**now come in if  case**

```
 var arrayname= [];

if (arrayname.length === 0) {
  // do your stuff 
}else{
// doyour stuff
 }
```

for object

```
jQuery.isEmptyObject({}); // true
jQuery.isEmptyObject({ test: "testvalue" }); // false
```

reference [$.isEmptyObject](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/)  and **[array length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)**

Comment: Ok thx, never heard of this. I've read the references but how do I incorporate this in the code above?

Comment: first $('.zoeken-select.listA').fadeIn(300); chnage this to  $('.zoeken-select .listA').fadeIn(300);